# Remap Lock key on Thinkpad Edge E531

Tags: windows, keyboard, thinkpad, remapping

My Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E531 (running Windows 7) has a few unneeded media keys above the numpad (Calculator, Lock computer, Web browser and Explorer) that I would like to remap to something more useful to me, namely Home, End, PgUp and PgDown. I've managed to remap three of the keys with common keymapping tools like KeyTweak and SharpKeys, but the Lock key eludes me.

The problem, as far as I can see, is that the Lock key isn't sending a single key code. It's instead pressing both the L and Windows keys at the same time, which is the key combo for locking Windows. Neither of the keycode mapping programs I've tried can handle this, and I can't seem to find a way to disable the key combo. Not that disabling it really matters, I can't remap the Windows key or the L key, since they are both rather useful for using a computer.

Is there any way for me to get the Lock key on my keyboard mapped to End?

Edit: I found a program called KeyCodes that registers all keyboard input. When I press the Lock key, I get a LWin KeyDown, and if I then release it I get an L KeyUp and an LWin KeyUp and the computer then locks itself. The key does not seem to generate any extraneous keycodes.

Comment: Does Lenovo ship a keyboard driver with its laptop?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - It doesn't seem to have a Lenovo driver installed, and I can't seem to find a keyboard driver on their website.

Comment: It is possible (albeit rare) for it's BIOS to have some sort of option that enables you to disable the Lock key. Other than that, try altering the Windows+L binding to something else.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - Well, of what I've read it's not possible to rebind the Win+L combination, but I'll have a look in the BIOS. The biggest problem with that is that I don't want to disable the key on the keyboard, I want to remap it.

Comment: If, as you said, the Lock key isn't being treated as different by some sort of software and is instead a shortcut to the Windows shortcut, maybe you're at a loss-loss situation. I'll link a utility I found earlier, as soon as I find it. UPDATE [link](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html). Read the app's FAQ as it describes how to find the scan codes you might need.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - I mentioned in the question that I had tried SharpKeys already, and that it didn't work. The FAQ also states that SharpKeys cannot remap key combinations.

Comment: Silly me, you did said that :P Consequence of reading almost at lightspeed. Well, as point 8 points out, there might be a chance that before Windows translates the keypress to the Lock mechanism, it receives a proper scan code, that SharpKeys can access and then assign to a different key. However I did try it on my keyboard (that also has a lock function, being Microsoft and all) and it didn't recognize it.

Comment: To add some more info. [This](http://jtsang.mvps.org/scancode_method.html) article has a listing on Microsoft keyboard scancodes, including the Log Off button, although if warns about installing Intellitype.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://superuser.com/a/727170/18151

This answer shows how to do it using AutoHotKey assuming registry edition is allowed