# Toggling the power saving mode on locking workstation

Tags: windows-10, desktop, power-management

I want to toggle the power saving mode of my desktop PC. I want that if i'm on my PC over the day it should preventing itself from shutting down, turning the monitor off and disabling the hard disk.

But if i'm not in my company i want to set it to the power save mode which should disable the hard disk and monitor after a specified amount of time. It should just toggles the modes if i press [WIN]+[L](lock screen) to the energy saving mode and if i unlock the computer back to the high capacity mode.

So how can i achieve this? Is this achievable with a Script or is there no way to do this?

Comment: Why not just put your PC in standby or hibernation when you're not at work? Look at the `Power Options` of Windows to setup the corresponding profiles. I'm not sure how you'd go about switching it while locking the screen but maybe a long timeout (say 5 hours?) would also suffice? During the night it would turn of the display/park the HDD and after you woke him up from that it would continue to function.

Comment: The reason is simple, i need multiple Services running in the background which i shouldn't stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default windows task scheduler to setup a task that runs on workstation lock/unlock. I haven't verified how reliable it is though. So just navigate to the Windows `Task Scheduler` and `Create a New Task` with a Trigger set to `On Workstation Lock` and change the power plan using `powercfg` to the energy saving one and use a Task with a Trigger `On Workstation Unlock` to toggle it back to "full power".

An other solution would be to try to rebind Win+L by e.g. using [AutoHotKey](https://superuser.com/questions/726988/how-to-remap-a-program-to-lock-windows-winl).