# Super+L not passed through and getting stuck with VcXsrv

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server, vcxsrv

Started using `VcXsrv` on Win10 in order to run fully fledged linux environment with a window manager.

Server is launched with `-keyhook` option so modifier keys get passed to the clients as well.

But <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is still problematic - it doesn't appear to be passed through, and causes <kbd>Super</kbd> key to get stuck; note getting stuck happens only when shortcut is used while vcxsrv window is active.

Other <kbd>Super</kbd>-related combinations (eg <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) work just fine.

Sidenote - I understand this keycombo is treated differently by Windows, but [following this registry edit](https://superuser.com/a/727170/179401) (disabling locking functionality), windows releases the keybinding, and can now be intercepted by other processes (eg the same [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/) script in that example, or Virtualbox).

Is it some oddity with this particular combination, or a bug with VcXsrv?

This issue is also posted under [project's bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/vcxsrv/bugs/85/).

Comment: What is "Super" key?

Comment: aka 'Win' or 'Windows' key.

Comment: Dang - Persistent issue, huh?  Asked in 2018, edited in 2020, and now bountied in 2022!

Comment: On Windows 11 you wouldn't need VcXsrv.

Comment: @harrymc are you referring to running vm in a hyper-v, available from windows 8 onwards? If not, could you please provide a solution.

Comment: No, I refer to upgrading Windows 10 to 11, for WSL to support graphical Linux apps.

Comment: @harrymc finally gave Win11 a go - as I understand Windows now packs its own window manager. It works fine for launching single GUI programs, but what I'm after is a full-blown desktop environment, meaning I need a window manager to run in vcxsrv.

Comment: VcXsrv seems to work with WSL2. For example see [this](https://codeburst.io/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-with-a-graphical-user-interface-in-wsl2-95911ee2997f?gi=d6c1f28423d1).

Comment: @harrymc why mention it, vcxsrv not working with wsl2 was never the problem?