# Remap `winKey + <anyKey>` while still having it be possible to lock computer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

Remap `winKey + <anyKey>` while still having it be possible to lock computer

Comment: Are you saying that disabling Winkey-L causes the system to not lock if you press Ctrl-Alt-Del and select "Lock" from the menu?

Comment: Ctrl Alt Del offers LOCK on all my Windows 10 and 11 installations. Have you tried repairing Windows?

Comment: Maybe the registry edit mucked up your computer.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen `I edited the registry to disable the winKey + l shortcut` ... no, you didn't ... look at the name of the registry key you created

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/726988/how-to-remap-a-program-to-lock-windows-winl#727170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the lock shortcut to `ctrl + F12` (you can change it to whatever you like).

AutohotkeyV1 script: (*Run as administrator*)

```
#InstallKeybdHook

; Disable win + l key locking (This line must come before any hotkey assignments in the .ahk file)

RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, DisableLockWorkstation, 1


;CTRL + F12 to lock computer
^F12::
; Renable locking
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, DisableLockWorkstation, 0
; Lock the computer
DllCall("LockWorkStation")
;after locking workstation force a reload of this script which effectively disables Win + L locking the computer again
Reload
```

[Credit](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/58260-is-there-really-no-way-to-disableremap-winl/)